# Any workarounds for extreme typing latency using Resharper 6.1 with VS-2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, intellisense, latency, resharper-6.0, javascript-intellisense

I recently installed **Resharper 6.1** in **VS-2010**. I'm using it with a rich web application with an Azure-based C# back end and JQuery and other Javascript libraries on the front end.

I love the way Resharper can parse my JS files and provide statement completion, and the code analysis has identified a number of style and syntax issues that I've already fixed.

HOWEVER, I am now experiencing **MAJOR typing latency** in my IDE as Resharper works its magic. I have a quad core Intel i5 dev box with 6GB of RAM, and the CPU is thrashing and memory usage shoots way up. The latency is so bad that any benefits from improved statement completion in JS files are lost.

I have a number of other JS plugins that I've temporarily disabled, but this didn't help. I then turned off Resharper's Intellisense and reverted back to VS-2010. This helped marginally, but Resharper is still making the editing experience latent.

I've run out of ideas about how to improve its performance. (Maybe, it's not possible to speed things up...) On paper, it's everything I've been looking for. But in practice, it has turned my speedy development machine into a 286 box from the 1980's running Windows 3.1. And as someone who was using 286-based Intel PC's back in the 1980's...that is not a good thing!

Comment: Quick update: I just uninstalled ReSharper so I can try out some other ideas. I want to see how far I can get with reference path directives in VS-2010 for JS Intellisense (e.g. /// <reference path="MyScripts.js" /> I haven't thrown in the towel completely, but if I can find something that's only a quarter as cool as ReSharper but that doesn't destroy my real-time editing experience in the IDE, that'll be good enough for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't mean to be facetious but my recommendation is to uninstall the thing. My personal take is that all the benefits that ReSharper offers are marginal compared to the headaches that it creates.

In my previous company I was supposed to use it but the moment I installed ReSharper it completely hijacked the Visual Studio native intellisense. My productivity actually went down instead of the other way around. Trying to figure out this thing through zillions of settings was quite frustrating.

I then went around the team and asked what everyone else thought of it. Two out of three devs hated it and had already uninstalled.

Comment: Accepting this as the answer. I ended up uninstalling ReSharper and am now using <Reference> directives in my JS files to get native VS-2010 JS intellisense. It's a manual, "per file" process, but now I have a responsive IDE again. My own view is that ReSharper is trying to do too many things at once. As you noted, it hijacks the editor and in my case made it totally latent and sluggish.

Answer (score 0):

You could try changing the priority of visual studio in Task Manager.

Also, it could be a memory leak. Maybe debug it, and then once you found the leak, report the bug to the ReSharper folks?

Comment: I just tried changing the priority in Task Manager, but I'm always getting an "Access denied" error. I always run VS-2010 as an admin anyway because this is required by Azure for debugging. I also tried starting the Task Manager using my admin credentials, but this didn't work, either. Am I missing something? Maybe it's not possible to change the priority of DEVENV...